# Value of a Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given that there are 2 iid random variables: $Y$ and $Z$. Also, given that the expectation of $Y$ is $\lambda$. Show that $Y = \lambda$ almost surely. It is also given that $Y$ is equal in distribution to $\frac{Y+Z}{2}$.

I realized that if I could show $\mathbb{E}(Y -\mathbb{E}Y)^2 = 0 $ then I am done. Thus I need to show that $Y=  \mathbb{E}Y$. Also, $\mathbb{E}(Y|Z)= \mathbb{E}Y$ as $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. I am stuck here. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- The expressions for variance are: $$\begin{split}\mathsf{Var}(Y)&=\mathsf E\left((Y-\mathsf E(Y))^2\right)\\&=\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(Y)^2\end{split}$$
- Because $Y$ and $(Y+Z)/2$ are identically distributed, therefore : $$\mathsf E(Y^2)=\mathsf E((Y+Z)^2 /4)$$
- Because $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, therefore they are uncorrelated; ie: $$\mathsf E(YZ)=\mathsf E(Y)\mathsf E(Z)$$
- Because $Y$ and $Z$ are identically distributed, therefore: $$\mathsf E(Y)=\mathsf E(Z)\\\mathsf E(Y^2)=\mathsf E(Z^2)$$

Put it together to show that the variance for $Y$ is $0$.

Comment: The result is true without the asumption that variances are finite